# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘[Type]=5 And Left([Name],1)<>"~" OORDER BY [Name]’

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to create a list box control that contains all of the queries except for the system queries. Recall that system query names begin with the `~` character.

When I try to write SQL code in the row source (in the property sheet) for my `frmQueries` form I keep getting an error saying:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression:
> '[Type]=5 And  Left([Name],1)<>"~" OORDER BY [Name]'

The code I entered is:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM MYSysObjects
WHERE [Type]=5 And Left([Name],1)<>"~" 
OORDER BY [Name];
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error or how I can fix it.

Comment: Change `OORDER` to `ORDER`

Comment: correct your syntax OORDER  replace it with ORDER

Answer (score 1):

`OORDER` should be `ORDER`, `MYSysObjects` should (presumably) be `MSysObjects`, and you can also replace `Left([Name],1)<>"~"` with `[Name] not like "~*"` (assuming MS Access instead of SQL Server).